# Creating custom controls

Tags: android, android-layout

I am coming from a Microsoft world so maybe a stupid question.

In UWP you can create a Custom control with public properties type of object, then define XAML for the Custom control where you layout elements - for example render the content of the objects in a grid rows, and you will end up with a reusable layout and you can reuse it in other places like so:

```
<CustomLayoutControl>
 <CustomLaoutControl.Header>
   //labels, etc
 <CustomLayoutControl.Header/>
 <CustomLayoutControl.Body>
   //custom controls
 <CustomLayoutControl.Body/>
<CustomLayoutControl/>
```

Is something possible in axml with Android? I can achieve this with inflating the layouts in activity/fragment and pasting it into respective frame layouts but I would like to do this in axml files declarative way.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the following links:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Basically you first create your XML layout, then create a class that will use that layout, and eventually you can place it in your main layout.